# sequelize group by result undefined

Tags: group-by, sequelize.js

i'm trying to get the result from sequelize query  **group by**

but when i want to get the value of count , it shows undefined

```
var models = require('../../config/sequelize');

models.device.findAll({
    attributes: [
        'type', 
        [models.sequelize.fn('count', models.sequelize.col('deviceId')),'count']
    ],
    group: ["device.type"]

    }).then(function (result) {

        result.forEach( function(e){

            console.log( e.count ) ;

        })
     }).catch(function(err) {
         console.log( "test group :"+JSON.stringify(err.message)) ;
}); ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming type and deviceId are the actual column name and not the aliases, try using raw: true and set columns using sequelize:

```
device.findAll({
    raw: true,
    attributes:[
        Sequelize.col('type'),
        [Sequelize.fn('count', Sequelize.col('deviceId')), 'count']
    ],
    group: [
        'device.type'
    ]
})
.then( devices => {
    console.log(devices.count); // or
    console.log(devices['count'])
})
.catch(/* */);
```